# Best practice when authorization and authentication is handled by different servers

Tags: node.js, authentication, authorization, jwt

I'm looking for a way to share SSO user table and secret key with other applications using Node.js API.

Current implementation: I have a central server which is used for Authentication. Authorization happens at the application level. A user signs up using my SSO server. The user information is stored in MySQL DB. when user logs in SSO will generate a JWT token, sends it to the client (stores it in a cookie). Then the client, for each request, will send the token instead of username and password.

I will have a product display page which will list all the applications.

Each of these applications has their own DB/file system to store user information. I thought about two ways to share the user information and secret key with each of these applications.

Design 1:

1. You copy the value of the JWT from a cookie, decode it in your application and then try to insert user information into the respective database/file
2. This operation happens in the product display page of SSO when a user clicks on a particular application
3. Every application won’t have user information stored unless the user clicks on App in the SSO product display page.

Design-2: Applies for both user management and a key share

1. We explicitly configure all the application servers in SSO
2. We provide an API to send the user data to the application

How do I efficiently manage to add, delete, update user information across multiple applications and share the secret key among all the apps? How should I approach it?